# adding a URL to a Microsoft.Web.Optimization bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Is it possible to add a url from another domain to the bundling in `Microsoft.Web.Optimization`?

I want to add a reference to replace the following link:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

My code for creating a css bundle which works with local files is as below:

```
Bundle cssCommon = new Bundle("~/cssCommon", typeof(CssMinify));
cssCommon.AddDirectory("~/content/", "aom.common.*", false);
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(cssCommon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually leaving that content on the other host is probably a better thing to do.

- You benefit from the Google's global distribution potentially this means that the font may be 'closer' on the internet and have less lag than your actual web server.
- You can download the content in parallel with your main content (each host is a separate set of downloads threads so it won't block your existing content or add to the total transfer time of that content)
- You benefit from Google's server resilience and up time.

The end user real world experience may actually be better as a result.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't really make sense because bundling reduces the number of requests from the website's server. Referencing goodleapis is obviously on another server.

There is the concept of [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)s though, and these can be changed depending on the release, this link has some useful information on [using a CDN with Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).